# How to disable or enable letterboxing and adjust UI5 for the widescreen?

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori, widescreen

I have an UI5-based app (1.66+), which works correctly, but there are huge empty spaces on the left and right sides of the screen (aka [letterboxing](https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/letter-boxing/) is on):

[image: Widescreen SAPUI5 app]

I want to disable letterboxing to use the entire screen space.

I tried the following approaches so far:

1. To use `"fullWidth": true` in `sap.ui` section of **manifest.json**
2. To add desktop-related classes to the HTML-tag in **index.html**:

```html
<html class="sap-desktop sapUiMedia-Std-Desktop sapUiMedia-StdExt-LargeDesktop">
```

3. To add `appWidthLimited: false` to **index.html**:

```js
<script>
    sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function () {
        new sap.m.Shell({
            app: new sap.ui.core.ComponentContainer({
                height: "100%",
                name: "APPNAME"
            }),
            appWidthLimited: false
        }).placeAt("content");
    });
</script>
```

Just like it is described in «[How to customise Shell container in SAPUI5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46730195)».

But none of them works for me.

**Update:**
I succeeded to solve the issue via a static XML-template — just add `<Shell id="shell" appWidthLimited="false">` to the main XML-template, but now I want to understand how to implement it via JS in `new sap.m.Shell(…)` definition.

The starting point for code experiments is below.

**index.html**:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>widescreen</title>
        <script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
            src="../../resources/sap-ui-core.js"
            data-sap-ui-theme="sap_fiori_3"
            data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{"letterboxing.widescreen": "./"}'
            data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge"
            data-sap-ui-oninit="module:sap/ui/core/ComponentSupport"
            data-sap-ui-async="true"
            data-sap-ui-frameOptions="trusted">
        </script>
    </head>
    <body class="sapUiBody">
        <div data-sap-ui-component data-name="letterboxing.widescreen" data-id="container" data-settings='{"id" : "widescreen"}' id="content"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Component.js**:

```js
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/UIComponent",
    "sap/ui/Device",
    "letterboxing/widescreen/model/models"
], function (UIComponent, Device, models) {
    "use strict";

    return UIComponent.extend("letterboxing.widescreen.Component", {

        metadata: {
            manifest: "json"
        },

        init: function () {
            // call the base component's init function
            UIComponent.prototype.init.apply(this, arguments);

            // enable routing
            this.getRouter().initialize();

            // set the device model
            this.setModel(models.createDeviceModel(), "device");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ok, so there seems to be many similar questions regarding how to disable/enable letterboxing. This answer should provide a solution for each case:

## Standalone Apps

Look for the instantiation of `sap.m.Shell` in your project and configure its `appWidthLimited` property accordingly.

**For example:**

[image: SAP Web IDE searching in project]

### In `index.html` or in a module assigned to `data-sap-ui-on-init`

```js
sap.ui.require([
  "sap/m/Shell",
  "sap/ui/core/ComponentContainer",
], (Shell, ComponentContainer) => new Shell({
  appWidthLimited: false|true, // <-- default: true
  // ...
}).placeAt("content"));
```

### In root view

```xml
<Shell xmlns="sap.m" appWidthLimited="false|true">
  <App>
    <!-- ... -->
```

Of course, the `Shell` can be configured dynamically in JS too with `myShell.setAppWidthLimited`.

**Note:** if the letterboxing is not required, consider removing `sap.m.Shell` entirely. There is **no real purpose of `sap.m.Shell` if the application always runs with full width or embedded in FLP.**

[API reference: **`sap.m.Shell`**](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.m.Shell)
[UX guideline: Letterboxing](https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/letter-boxing/#guidelines)

---

## Apps on SAP Fiori launchpad (FLP)

The app or component …:

- should **not** contain `sap.m.Shell` anywhere (please check the root view).
- launches from the FLP instead (no `index.html`).

### Statically in `manifest.json`

```json
"sap.ui": {
  "fullWidth": true|false
```

Documentation: [Descriptor for Applications, Components, and Libraries](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/be0cf40f61184b358b5faedaec98b2da)

### Dynamically at runtime

```js
// AppConfiguration required from "sap/ushell/services/AppConfiguration"
AppConfiguration.setApplicationFullWidth(true|false); //*
```

According to SAP Fiori design guidelines, switching the letterbox state during runtime is allowed:

> Letterboxing can be switched on or off [...] for individual pages within an application. [...]
>
> In some cases, applications may need to have the flexibility to change the width at runtime for different views. [...] Apps can change the width in the `AppConfiguration` service at runtime for different views.

* The API `setApplicationFullWidth`, however, is **deprecated since UI5 1.120.** If you really need switching the letterbox state during the application runtime, please **create a new customer ticket** at https://me.sap.com/getsupport with the component CA-FLP-FE-UI.

[API reference: **`sap.ushell.services.AppConfiguration`**](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ushell.services.AppConfiguration)
[UX guideline: Letterboxing](https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/letter-boxing/#guidelines)

---

### ⚡ Limitations

Currently, the **static** setting `"fullWidth": false` is **not** supported by:

- <del>FLP on Cloud Foundry in BTP (Deployed apps running in an iframe). SAP is still looking into it.</del>

   → **FIXED** since SAPUI5 1.120.5
- Apps generated via *[SAP Fiori elements](https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/smart-templates/)* — by design.

Comment: Perfect answer, thanks a lot for making distinction between the two scenarios !

Comment: I am absolutely dumbfounded who this is STILL an issue

Comment: @Fjaoos The issue with the FLP on CF should be fixed by now. Could you try again?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Available OpenUI5 Versions](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/versionoverview.html) the newest OpenUI5 version is 1.65.0. How is you app based on 1.66.0?

Setting `appWidthLimited: false` on the `sap.m.Shell` should do the work. Check out this example ([plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/2P3RPdCkWgJWyGvwCSmL?p=preview) / [github](https://gist.github.com/piotr-koca/c490c0f578c32f8e942487b7a07294f1)) (in the Plunker run preview in a new window)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that removing the shell control from index.html:

```
sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function () {
    sap.ui.require(["sap/ui/core/ComponentContainer"], function (ComponentContainer) {
        new ComponentContainer({
            name: "yourProject",
            async: true,
            manifest: true,
            height: "100%"

        }).placeAt("content");

    });
});
```

instead of this:

```
<script>
    sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function () {
        new sap.m.Shell({
            app: new sap.ui.core.ComponentContainer({
                height: "100%",
                name: "APPNAME"
            }),
            appWidthLimited: false
        })
        .placeAt("content");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Could you please, elaborate your answer? I don't really get what does it mean «instead of this». I don't have such code in my index.html

Comment: OK, Can you post your index.html on your question?

Comment: Okay. On your question you said on step 3: "To add appWidthLimited: false to index.html" and then you pasted the script on your index.html. My sugestion is that you remove completely the object sap.m.Shell. Check the code you pasted. There is an object called sap.m.Shell. Remove this object (check my example again). Cheers

Comment: I just replaced `sap.m.Shell` code in index.html with your code snippet, there is no left-right margins anymore, but now «Title» header is duplicated and there is a vertical scrolling. I wondered what is the reason for such behaviour?

Comment: I’ll try to do an example. But I think my should be the accepted answer since you were able to remove the letterbox

Answer (score 0):

Static implementation via XML-template:

```xml
<mvc:View controllerName="letterboxing.widescreen.controller.index" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" displayBlock="true" xmlns="sap.m">
    <Shell id="shell" appWidthLimited="false">
        <App id="app">
            <pages>
                <Page id="page" title="{i18n>title}">
                    <content></content>
                </Page>
            </pages>
        </App>
    </Shell>
</mvc:View>
```

For dynamic implementation via JS-controller with `appWidthLimited: false` in `sap.m.Shell`, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55867413

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, `AppConfiguration.setApplicationFullWidth(true);` does not work for me. I don't have a valid application container.

I solved the problem in this, admittedly hacky, way: In my app controller, I added this implementation of the `onAfterRendering` method:

```js
onAfterRendering: function () {
    var oElement = this.getView().byId("idAppControl").$();
    while (oElement && oElement.hasClass) {
        if (oElement.hasClass("sapUShellApplicationContainerLimitedWidth")) {
            oElement.removeClass("sapUShellApplicationContainerLimitedWidth");
            break;
        }
        oElement = oElement.parent();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if such approach is a safe-one from the performance point of view. I'm not so familiar with UI5's internals, but I would try to avoid `window.setTimeout` with `while (oElement && oElement.hasClass)` inside since it might trigger heavy and undesired DOM re-rendering by calling a `removeClass` in a loop. I would try to figure out what is the original reason for your issue.

Comment: @MikeB. The code is actually just doing (removing a style class) what the "official" approach via `AppConfiguration.setApplicationFullWidth(true);` does. Ah, and I forgot to add a `break`.

Comment: ..and I also forgot  the traversal through the dom tree.

Comment: As far as I understand, `AppConfiguration.setApplicationFullWidth(true);` is executed once, at the app startup. The question how often `window.setTimeout` is executed? And is there any real need to use `window.setTimeout` here?

Comment: The App Controller is also created only once. I need to use window.timeout because the actual html is rendered after the code is executed. I could probably also put it into another method, like `onAfterRendering`

Comment: @MikeB. I changed my answer to use the `onAfterRendering` method.

Comment: You might have a `sap.m.Shell` somewhere in your project. Could you please check again? As mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/56137602/5846045, the app should not contain a Shell and launch from FLP. Does at least setting `fullWidth: true|false` in `manifest.json` work?

Comment: @BoghyonHoffmann The app does not have a `sap.m.Shell`, so I can't set the fullWidth there. I think I tried using `fullWidth` in `manifest.json`, but that didn't help.